# update textview evey click without losing frames

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, textview, frames

so everytime i reach about 750 on textview my app start losing frames
somone have any advice for me on how to make the code work better without losing any frames?

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

     imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);



    counter=1000;




    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("" + counter);

            counter--;
            if (counter<999) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
            }
            if (counter<950) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon3);
            }
            if (counter<900) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon4);
            }
            if (counter<850) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon5);
            }
            if (counter<800) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon6);
            }
            if (counter<750) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon7);
            }
            if (counter<700) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon8);
            }
            if (counter<650) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon9);
            }
            if (counter<600) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon10);
            }
            if (counter<550) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon11);
            }
            if (counter<500) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon12);
            }
            if (counter<450) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon13);
            }
            if (counter<400) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon14);
            }
            if (counter<350) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon15);

            }
            if (counter<300) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon16);

            }
            if (counter<250) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon17);

            }
            if (counter<200) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon18);

            }
            if (counter<150) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon19);

            }
            if (counter<100) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon20);

            }
            if (counter<25) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon21);

            }
            if (counter<1) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon22);

            }
            if (counter<0) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                counter=1000;
                textView.setText("" + counter);

            }


            Random rnd = new Random();
                int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
                textView.setTextColor(color);


        }
    });
```

}
}

Comment: How about reversing the order and putting an `else` in front of each `if` so it's not evaluating every condition every time?

Comment: i tried it it just change it once and then never trigger the others for some reason

Comment: it worked man :] ty a lot